# DHCP-provided DNS Server with wrong route in Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: server, dns, dhcp, 22.04, netplan

On fresh install of Ubuntu Server 22.04 (ubuntu-22.04-live-server-amd64.iso) on my network, I can not use the DHCP-Provided DNS Servers which are a on a different subnet : routes to that subnet are also provided by the DHCP Server, but it seems that Ubuntu 22.04 is trying to enforce the default gateway to reach the DNS Server (which is not ok). With Ubuntu 20.04 (ubuntu-20.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso), the problem is not present and everything is working correctly.

This is my [network architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lS0h.jpg)

The DHCP server is providing this configuration :

- `Option 003 Router : 10.1.20.251`
- `Option 006 DNS Servers : 10.1.10.11,10.1.10.12`
- `121 Classless Static Routes : 10.1.10.0/24 via 10.1.20.1, 10.1.11.0/24 via 10.1.20.1, 0.0.0.0/32 via 10.1.20.251`

On Ubuntu Server **20.04**, this my netplan configuration (fresh install) :

```
root@ubsrv2004:~# cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

On Ubuntu Server **22.04**, this my netplan configuration (fresh install) :

```
root@ubsrv2204:~# cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

On Ubuntu Server **20.04**, this route table after getting DHCP configuration :

```
root@ubsrv2004:~# ip r
default via 10.1.20.251 dev ens160 proto dhcp src 10.1.20.15 metric 100
10.1.10.0/24 via 10.1.20.1 dev ens160 proto dhcp src 10.1.20.15 metric 100
10.1.11.0/24 via 10.1.20.1 dev ens160 proto dhcp src 10.1.20.15 metric 100
10.1.12.0/24 via 10.1.20.1 dev ens160 proto dhcp src 10.1.20.15 metric 100
10.1.20.0/24 dev ens160 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.20.15
```

On Ubuntu Server **22.04**, this route table after getting DHCP configuration :

```
root@ubsrv2204:~# ip r
default via 10.1.20.251 dev ens160 proto dhcp src 10.1.20.13 metric 100
10.1.10.0/24 via 10.1.20.1 dev ens160 proto dhcp src 10.1.20.13 metric 100
10.1.10.11 via 10.1.20.251 dev ens160 proto dhcp src 10.1.20.13 metric 100
10.1.10.12 via 10.1.20.251 dev ens160 proto dhcp src 10.1.20.13 metric 100
10.1.11.0/24 via 10.1.20.1 dev ens160 proto dhcp src 10.1.20.13 metric 100
10.1.12.0/24 via 10.1.20.1 dev ens160 proto dhcp src 10.1.20.13 metric 100
10.1.20.0/24 dev ens160 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.20.13 metric 100
10.1.20.1 dev ens160 proto dhcp scope link src 10.1.20.13 metric 100
10.1.20.251 dev ens160 proto dhcp scope link src 10.1.20.13 metric 100
```

As you can see, I have 2 routes for the DNS Servers 10.1.10.11 & 10.1.10.12. Theses routes are totally incorrects because the DNS Servers are reachable through 10.1.20.1 and not 10.1.20.251.

```
10.1.10.11 via 10.1.20.251 dev ens160 proto dhcp src 10.1.20.13 metric 100
10.1.10.12 via 10.1.20.251 dev ens160 proto dhcp src 10.1.20.13 metric 100
```

If I setup the DNS manually by adding this to both netplan configuration :

```
  dhcp4-overrides:
     use-dns: false
  nameservers:
     addresses: [10.1.10.11]
```

I still have the same problem.

What could cause the difference between thoses 2 fresh installs of ubuntu server 20.04 and 22.0.4 ? And how can I configure correctly Ubuntu 22.04 in order to get the DHCP-Provided routes and DHCP-Provided-DNSServers working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create "drop-in" configuration for each of the `.network` configuration files that adds the configuration to disable the creation of the routes to the DNS servers.

```
for i in /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-*.network; do 
  drop_in="/etc/systemd/network/$(basename ${i}).d"
  mkdir -p "${drop_in}"
  cat <<EOF > "${drop_in}/override.conf"
[DHCPv4]
RoutesToDNS=false
EOF
done
```

The default install for Ubuntu Server will use *netplan* to generate configuration for *systemd-networkd*.  The routes for the DNS servers can be disabled in *systemd-networkd* using the configuration key `RoutesToDNS`.

The `RoutesToDNS` configuration is not supported by *netplan* directly.  Using a "drop-in" file allows adding *systemd-networkd* configuration to the configuration generated by *netplan*.

**links**

- https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man5/systemd.network.5.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. That explain everything... I will use a static IP for that Ubuntu Server (I usually use debian which is not impacted).

It's a kind of weird and unusual behavior, I have never seen something like that in other distributions or OS. 

I tried to find why it's like that but it seems that only reason behind that is that someone thought "it would make a lot of sense" : https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/11961