# Specifying systemd-networkd options via netplan

Tags: networking, dhcp, netplan, systemd-networkd

I have a need to use a systemd-networkd configuration option on my system:

```
[DHCPV6]
RapidCommit=no
```

Is it possible to add this option via netplan somehow? Or do I have to disable netplan completely to add more complex systemd-networkd options?

Comment: You can try a solution like https://askubuntu.com/a/1410381/376778 .  You would replace the content of the `override.conf` file with the configuration you want to use.  I don't see any mention of `RapidCommit` in the netplan source code so I assume that setting is not supported.

Comment: Thanks. So this drop-in configuration will merge with the existing netplan configuration for that interface to add extra options? That sounds like it will do the job.